# Javascript forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript, foreach

I'm trying to add a click event to all my edit icons. Each icon has an ID that I'm using to call them.

```html
<div><img src="" id="editCatsSVG" /></div>
```

Here's my js file below.

```js
const edicatsIcon = document.querySelector('#editCatsSVG'),
      deleteCatsIcon = document.querySelector('#deleteCatsSVG');
      
const catsActionsModal = document.querySelector('#catsActions'),
      closeCatsModal = document.querySelector("#closeModalIConButton");




edicatsIcon.forEach(addEventListener("click", function(){
    catsActionsModal.style.display = "flex";
}));

closeCatsModal.addEventListener("click", function(){
    catsActionsModal.style.display = "none";
    
});
```

Is there a way I can add the forEach func so when all the editcatsIcon is clicked, the modal shows?

please?

Many thanks.

Comment: Because `edicatsIcon` is either undefined, or is not an array. But you've not included enough of your code to determine the issue.

Comment: Because querySelector is not a collection. How you are using forEach is also wrong. You are calling a forEach method and assigning what it returns to the forEach. You are not calling that code on each iteration. You need it to be a function call.

Comment: @Lissy93 thanks for the reply. I've added all my js code above. It's clear that I have icons/images with the editctatsIcon as the id. Then from the js file, I want to make sure that when anyone of the icons/images is clicked, as my code says, the modal should be display flex or hidden.

Comment: @epascarello, I'm beginning to grab what you're saying. But is there a way  I  achieve what I'm trying to do? I just can't think of a way to do this stuff to work.

Comment: Note you can't have a number of elements with the same id. Ids must be unique.

Comment: Better solution. Use event delegation and forget about looping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use `querySelectorAll` instead of querySelector, and also check if the element exists before running a forEach on it, like this:

```
const arr = document.querySelectorAll(".class" || "#id");

arr && arr.forEach(function () { ... })
```

Comment: Ids need to be unique so it's not clear what `querySelectorAll` is going to achieve.

Comment: "Also check if the element exists," I think that's the thing. Thank you soooo much. This is what I needed.

Comment: @youngP Glad I could help!  Don't forget to mark this as answer in case any one who has this question gets to it much faster :)

Answer (score 2):

`document.querySelector` returns an `Element` or `null` - neither of which have `forEach` as a method (see [querySelctor on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)).

Just repeat what you are doing for closeCatsModal:

```js
edicatsIcon.addEventListener("click", function(){
    catsActionsModal.style.display = "flex";
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`const edicatsIcon = document.querySelector('#editCatsSVG')` will return one element, not an array of elements. Also, you're querying for elements with the id `editCatsSVG`, and you can't have duplicate ids.

This

```js
edicatsIcon.forEach(addEventListener("click", function(){
    catsActionsModal.style.display = "flex";
}));
```

Should be

```js
edicatsIcon.addEventListener("click", function(){
    catsActionsModal.style.display = "flex";
});
```

Comment: I actually want all my icons/img to have that click event. So what I did was I added querySelectorAll and then I checked for the function first, before writing the functions.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the earlier answer. `Element.querySelector()` return a single element (which is not iterable with .forEach). `Element.querySelectorAll()` returns a `NodeList` iterable (array like) which in modern browsers supports .forEach().

If you want to select a single element, use `Element.querySelector()`, if you want to select multiple, use `Element.querySelectorAll()`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the contributions. What I did was simple:

I added a `querySelectorAll` to the icons below

`const edicatsIcon = document.querySelectorAll('#editCatsSVG'),`

Then I checked if any of the elements has a click event, if true, I called my function below

```
edicatsIcon.forEach(n => n.addEventListener("click", openModal));

function openModal() {
    catsActionsModal.style.display = "flex";
}
```

And I got what I needed. Thanks all.